# Particle filter in R – trivial code example

Tags: r, particle-filter

I am looking for a simple code example of how to run a Particle Filter in R. The pomp package appears to support the state space math bit, but the examples are a little tricky to follow programmatically for a simple OO developer such as myself, particularly how to load the observed data into a pomp object.

- Examples here: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pomp/vignettes/intro_to_pomp.pdf

Lets say I have a csv file with 1 column of noisy data as input, and I would like to run it through a Particle Filter in order to hopefully clean it up, with the output being the estimations, to another csv file.

```
 y <- read.csv("C:/Dev/VeryCleverStatArb/inputData.csv", header=FALSE)
 #CSV to Pomp object ???
 #Run Particle Filter
 #Write estimates to csv.
```

The main difficulty with the examples is loading csv data into a pomp object.

A very simple state space model should be good enough for now.

Any ideas for the R-curious?

Comment: This might be useful for anyone looking into pairs trading, or algorithmic trading in general, where these is an economic  relationship surrounded by noise.

Comment: IMHO you are better off coding the filter yourself...

Comment: Awesome! Samples / tips / pointers for everyone viewing this? An alternate solution's better than no solution.

Comment: @user1180428: I've edited my answer, which may now provide a possible alternative for you.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: It seems that most particle filter packages are gone now. However, I have been playing with LaplacesDemon (a Bayesian MCMC package) and it does have the PMC (Population Monte Carlo) function which implements PMC, which is a type of particle filter. Maybe too much machinery for a quick particle filter kind of thing, but a package well worth learning.

You can find package and tutorials at [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/LaplacesDemon/index.html).

ORIGINAL: To be honest, in the simplest case, `pomp` is hard to use. It's very flexible for anything you might want to do, but it's like using a space ship to go to the grocery store.

Have you tried looking at Kalman filters (if your data might satisfy assumptions of the Kalman filter), including base functions `tsSmooth` and `StructTS` (univariate only), and package `dlm`? I'd also take a look at `loess` and other smoothers.

I *hope* I'm wrong and someone hops on here with a quick, "Here's how to do it for simple univariate data such as you have with some modest assumptions." I'd love to be able to use the package myself.

Comment: Been there hacked that. Unfortunately, a simple moving average seems to nail a useable signal better than the Kalman filter in this, and many other examples -- Kalman: [link](http://www.houstonwelsh.com/tmp/kalman20120204.PNG) , SMA: [link](http://www.houstonwelsh.com/tmp/sma20120204.PNG) The data is stationary, is so far as a Dickey Fuller p < 0.01. Maybe I'm doing it wrong. A script to run a particle filter on this data, and other pairs trading candidates would be awesome (I think).

Answer (score 0):

In 2017, Dahlin & Schön published a really good article with R scripts for both Kalman and Particle filters, as well as Metropolis-Hasting algorithm:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.01707.pdf

It is not the most efficient code (its in R only), but very well made.